# Rails 3.2.8 with authlogic returning "undefined method `each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, each, authlogic

I've been trying to set up authlogic with my Rails 3.2.8 server. I can get everything mostly working, but whenever I try to view my usernames I get this  error.

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I haven't seen any reason as to why this happens with rails apps. It works if I grab an old example, but not when I set it up with a recent version. Anyone know why this is happening? This is the specific code generated by rails that causes the issue, as far as I know it should be working.

```
<% @user_sessions.each do |user_session| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user_session.email %></td>
    <td><%= user_session.password %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_session %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_session_path(user_session) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_session, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit:

This is where @user_sessions is being set, in my config/routes.rb I have this

```
resources :users, :user_sessions
match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

And my models/user.rb looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

This is what my UsersController index looks like. Edit again:

```
def index
  @users = User.all 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
```

And this is what my UserSessionController looks like:

```
 def index
   @user_sessions = UserSession.all

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @user_sessions }
   end
 end
```

Note: I had this commented out thinking it was an issue. If that isn't commented out it returns

```
undefined method `all' for UserSession:Class
```

Comment: `@user_sessions` is `nil`. Where is this being set?

Comment: Could you please show us where you define your @user_sessions variable?

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast reply! Definitely a sign of a healthy rails community! I updated the post with what I believe is the data you're looking for.

Comment: FYI, you should try and provide all of this information at once. Ignore my answer please.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize that this was a part of the issue. I posted it in response to your answer. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Don't worry about it. Anyway, It appears that `UserSession` class does not extend `ActiveRecord`. Should it? Do you have a 'user_sessions' table in your database?

Comment: I don't believe so, I'm extending "Authlogic::Session::Base" and I don't have a database for UserSession, it shouldn't need one. This is the guide I was following if it helps at all. http://www.logansbailey.com/2010/10/06/how-to-setup-authlogic-in-rails-3/

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something, but I've never seen a way to list all user sessions in Authlogic as you're trying to do.

Comment: Right, sorry. Well it's pretty simple. There is no `all` method for `AuthLogic`. Try `User.logged_in` -  I think it returns all currently logged in users. [Read this](http://blog.eizesus.com/2010/01/find-all-online-users-with-authlogic-29-1-2010/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this](http://blog.eizesus.com/2010/01/find-all-online-users-with-authlogic-29-1-2010/)

Try

```
@user_sessions = User.logged_in
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for all of your help! Do I need to change all UserSession's in my UserSessionsController to User like that?

Comment: You're welcome. You need to change it wherever you were attempting `UserSession.all`

Comment: Oh, I mean the variable that I'm using. I'm going from "@user_sessions = UserSession.logged_in" to "@user_sessions = User.logged_in" Which I find a little confusing.

Comment: It needs to be `User.logged_in` and not `UserSession.logged_in`